# Is this set compct?

Tags: general-topology, functions, continuity, differential-topology

Assuming $\exists \alpha>0$ such that the set $\omega_{\alpha}=\{x~\epsilon~\mathbb{R}^{n}:f(x)\leq \alpha \}$ is bounded and $\omega_{\alpha}\backslash\partial \omega_{\alpha}$ is open and non-empty with $f(x)~\epsilon~C^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{n},\mathbb{R})$, then is the set $\omega_{\alpha}$ compact?

Comment: It is compact independent of the assumption about the boundary since $f$ is continuous and $(-\infty,\alpha]$ is closed

Comment: @FShrike I have one doubt about it. So, if we take the definition of closed set as it's complement being open then yes it is closed. But in view of the other definition that a set is closed if and only if it contains all of its boundary points, how's this satisfied?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is something to address here (I am posting as an answer as it is good not to answer in the comments).

Firstly: as the complement of $(\alpha,\infty)$, $(-\infty,\alpha]$ is closed and as $f$ is continuous (we do not need $C^1$) $f^{-1}(-\infty,\alpha]=\{x\in\Bbb R^n:f(x)\le\alpha\}$ is the continuous preimage of a closed set, hence closed (since its complement is the continuous preimage of an open set which is open). By the Heine-Borel theorem, or really just some general metric space theory ($\Bbb R^n$ is complete, so all closed subsets are complete; all its bounded subsets are totally bounded, hence all its closed and bounded subsets are complete and totally bounded, which is equivalent to compactness in a metric space) we have that $\omega_\alpha$ is compact.

The ""other"" definition that a closed set contains all its limit points *is the same definition*. E.g. $(-\infty,\alpha]$ has the trivial limit points inside of it and the boundary point $\alpha$ also contained in it; **note that $-\infty\notin\Bbb R$ so is not a limit point in the parent space**, so the fact that $-\infty\notin(-\infty,\alpha]$ is not relevant as it is not a bona fide limit point (but it would be in the extended reals).

Equivalence proof:

> Let $F$ have open complement in the topological space $X$; suppose $x\in X$ is a limit point of $F$ not in $F$. Then, as a limit point, all neighbourhoods of $x$ intersect $F$. However, since $x\in X\setminus F$ which is open, there is a neighbourhood $X\setminus F\supseteq\mathcal{O}\ni x$ so that $\mathcal{O}\cap F=\emptyset$, a contradiction as we no longer have that *all* neighbourhoods of $x$ intersect $F$ thus is $x$ not a limit point.
>
> Now let $F$ contain all its limit points. Suppose $X\setminus F$ is not open i.e. there is an $x\in X\setminus F$ for which no neighbourhood $\mathcal{O}\ni x$ satisfies $\mathcal{O}\subseteq X\setminus F$. Then as $X=(X\setminus F)\sqcup F$, we must have $\mathcal{O}\cap F\neq\emptyset$. As this holds for all neighbourhoods $\mathcal{O}$ of $x$, $x$ is a limit point of $F$ hence $x\in F$, a contradiction.